# How can I access lock screen Apps on Android like iOS 7 -- Galaxy S4 on Sprint

Tags: lock-screens

I am a recent covert from iPhone. the one thing i miss, which is even more prevalent with iOS7, is the ability to access basic apps (e.g. phone, flashlight, wifi toggle) from the locked home screen without having to unlock/enter my security code. Even the 3rd party Android home screen apps that allow you "access" apps on the home screen, still require you to unlock your phone after you select the app.

How can i access apps directly from the a locked home screen?

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, you can't access normal apps from the lock screen: you can only access *lock screen widgets*. They're like home screen widgets, but the app they come from has designated them as suitable for the lock screen: they may have better ways to keep sensitive data hidden than normal home screen widgets.

Not all Samsung phones support lock screen widgets. For example, the Galaxy S III doesn't (unless you install a 3rd-party lock screen app, or a custom ROM), because its lock screen was designed before Google added lock screen widgets to Android. The Galaxy S4 does, though, so you just need to add the widget of your choice to it!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a 3rd-party app such as [Widget Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker&hl=en). Dev offers great support, and this application is consistently updated. It also works very well, and is customizable to your needs.

Comment: I would also recommend https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.dashclock&hl=en_GB Dash Clock widget, made AFAIK by a google employee and has hundreds of extensions. It is a lock screen WIDGET though and not a lock screen replacement like you linked to... Why not both eh? :) Also many apps support lock screen widgets in Android 4.2.2+ such as Gmail, Facebook, Messaging etc.